# How does Windows 7's activation works?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When installing Windows 7 or Vista, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-installing-windows-7-or-vista-does-the-language-version-architecture-64)

I know there have been issues with it and some of its predecessors and I've run into some of those, but I still don't understand all that is going on. Some specific questions.

- Can a given key be transferred to another machine? If so, will it require a phone call?
- Will an activation revert with hardware changes? If so, what hardware?
- Are there any counts/limits on activations?
- How do activations work if I am using virtualization? Will a single activation work for a Bootcamp image (dual boot) on a Mac as well as a Parallels/VMWare Fusion instance (virtualization)?
- What is the countdown listed when a system has not been activated?
- Are there differences between developer, consumer and business copies?
- Can I activate without an internet connection?
- Can different activation keys enable different functionality?

Comment: entirely too many questions in a single post.

Comment: I gave answering them all succinctly a shot...for larger detail on answers ask the questions separately or check out the MCP for windows 7 study guide at a local bookstore

Comment: some, if not all, of these questions have been asked previously

Comment: @Gareth a low-views closed question doesn't need its title edited. Leave it or flag for deletion.

Comment: Sorry, it's for this meta post: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3697/whats-up-with-window-xp-and-window-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Can a given key be transferred to another machine? If so, will it require a phone call?*

depends on how many times it was used

- *Will an activation revert with hardware changes? If so, what hardware?*

yes, i seem to remember it being based on the quantity of hardware changes

- *Are there any counts/limits on activations?*

yes

- *How do activations work if I am using virtualization? Will a single activation work for a Bootcamp image (dual boot) on a Mac as well as a Parallels/VMWare Fusion instance (virtualization)?*

if the virtual hardware looks like different devices to the OS no

- *What is the countdown listed when a system has not been activated?*

time before it limits functionality to only activation

- *Are there differences between developer, consumer and business copies?*

yes - for detailed licensing answers check the MS website

- *Can I activate without an internet connection?*

yes - requires phone-call

- *Can different activation keys enable different functionality?*

yes - all versions of 7 for a single architecture are on the DVD to facilitate the "anytime upgrade" functionality

Comment: Can you play with editing on your answer, please. It's difficult to distinguish between his questions and your answers.

Answer (score 6):

All your questions can be answered by the following websites, which I found by searching for `Microsoft Activation site:microsoft.com` on Google.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302806

and

http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/cu_sc_prodact_master

Answer (score 3):

> Can a given key be transferred to another machine? If so, will it require a phone call?

If it's not an OEM edition, yes & no

> Will an activation revert with hardware changes? If so, what hardware?

Yes. Motherboard/CPU/Hard disk/RAM

> Are there any counts/limits on activations?

Yes.

> How do activations work if I am using virtualization? Will a single activation work for a Bootcamp image (dual boot) on a Mac as well as a Parallels/VMWare Fusion instance (virtualization)?

I doubt.

> What is the countdown listed when a system has not been activated?

If the product is not activated, it enters into [Reduced Functionality mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925582)

> Are there differences between developer, consumer and business copies?

No.

> Can I activate without an internet connection?

Yes

> Can different activation keys enable different functionality?

No, not within the same SKU

Comment: i  think when he says different activation keys, he means different SKUs

Comment: @aking hmm perhaps .. if so your answer covers it :-)

Answer (score 1):

•Can a given key be transferred to another machine? If so, will it require a phone call?
**If its an OEM Key then no, if it is retail then yes but only legally if you have removed it from the other machine, unless it is a multiple user key**

•Will an activation revert with hardware changes? If so, what hardware?
**AFAIK you are allowed to change 3 pieces of HW in the machine before re-activation is required**

•Are there any counts/limits on activations?
**As long as they are legal no, although you will have to activate by phone after a certain number of activations - I'm read it is 5 in XP although I am not sure of the number for newer versions**

•How do activations work if I am using virtualization? Will a single activation work for a Bootcamp image (dual boot) on a Mac as well as a Parallels/VMWare Fusion instance (virtualization)?
**Not legally as this is 2 instances of windows.**

•What is the countdown listed when a system has not been activated?
**You get 30 days. After the countdown hasd expired certain things will be disabled i.e certain updates, you will receive Nag messages to encourage you to activate etc**

•Are there differences between developer, consumer and business copies?
**Yes different versions have different features, the more you pay the more you get**

•Can I activate without an internet connection?
**Yes you can activate by phone**

•Can different activation keys enable different functionality?
**Yes, in Vista and Windows 7 different keys 'unlock' different features. i.e the installation media for Home Premium and Ultimate is the same, the difference is the key you use.**

Answer (score 0):

> Can a given key be transferred to another machine? If so, will it require a phone call?

Only if it has been transferred between machines many times. If it's an OEM key, then it cannot be transferred legally.

> Will an activation revert with hardware changes? If so, what hardware?

It will, on changing a specific set of hardware such as NIC, GPU, CPU or motherboard.

> Are there any counts/limits on activations?

No - an activation phone call may be needed.

> How do activations work if I am using virtualization? Will a single activation work for a Bootcamp image (dual boot) on a Mac as well as a Parallels/VMWare Fusion instance (virtualization)?

You have to activate each installation, whether physical or virtual.

> What is the countdown listed when a system has not been activated?

I don't know.

> Are there differences between developer, consumer and business copies?

Developer copies have different licence terms, consumer copies can be used for almost anything, business copies have a volume key, I believe.

> Can I activate without an Internet connection?

Yes, on the phone.

> Can different activation keys enable different functionality?

They did with Vista, don't know about 7.